# image box horizontally alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to make the red box horizontally aligned
i gave display inline property to the imageBox class but its not working

providing my code below

```
<div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
            <div class="imageBox"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VXXPC/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.imageBox {display: inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VXXPC/13/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the display:inline; function is only for list items.

The best solution to make them display in a line, is to wrap them in a div, then give every box div a float:left;


HTML:

```
<div id="ImageBox_wrapper> 
   <div class="ImageBox></div>
   <div class="ImageBox></div>
   <div class="ImageBox></div>
   <div class="ImageBox></div>
   <div class="ImageBox></div>
   <div class="ImageBox></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ImageBox {
border:1px solid red;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
float: left;
```

If that doesn't work you can try adding a position:relative; to your .ImageBox css

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: I agree.  I would also add "overflow: hidden;" to ImageBox_wrapper to eliminate the float issue in parent elements.